# C# displaying sql result in table like structure

Tags: c#, ms-access, listbox

I got a MS-Access database table with columns like:

```
v1, v2, v3
```

I read this data into 3 different arrays namely:

```
av1, av2, av3
```

Now in my GUI I want to display this data into a listbox like a table structure, ex:

```
Title   Name    Salary
av1[0]  av2[0]  av3[0]
av1[1]  av2[1]  av3[1]
```

and so on

The entire structure is scrollable.

Do I need 3 listboxes placed side by side or is there some other way which supports a tabular display?

I'm not sure if I explained myself clearly, but I'm not getting an example/screenshot I can show.

Thanks

Comment: Is it in win forms? or web forms? I think you can use GridView or its alternatives, which support Tabular display

Comment: Your description is definitely confusing.  You mention using a single listbox, but then say you're looking for a tabular display.  Would an actual table of data (as long as it was scrollable) meet your requirements, or does it need to be a listbox?

Comment: Why read into three arrays? You'll want to select into something generic like a DataTable or a class of your own creation. Then use a GridView or similar and have the DataTable or a list of your class as the data source.

Comment: Both a ListView or for DB data preferred the DataGridView are tabular Controls in WinForms. In WPF you have the GridView and also the ListView. Listboxes are __always__ a bad choice. And you should read the Data into a DataTable, not arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into a gridView. Once the data is displayed, I also need the user to select an item (row), and when they click another button then some other action is performed on the selected item (row).

Answer (score 0):

How are you reading from Access? Assuming you are using `ADO .NET`, you probably have a `DataReader` object. The `ListView` control is one option but to simply display the data you can use the `DataGridView` control.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectFindUserByName);

connection.Open();
command.Connection = connection;
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
DataGridView1.DataSource = reader;
```